# Wordpress sub taxonomy template

Tags: custom-taxonomy, theme-development, template-hierarchy

Please see my code structure

Custom post type name : **product**

Custom taxonomy associated with product : **category**

Main category inside category taxonomy :**main1, main2 etc**

Sub taxonomy inside main1 : **sub1, sub2 etc**

I need to create template for all sub category and this templates are same.
so I need to create one template only that is suitable for all category taxonomy.

Also I need to know **how to get the current taxonomy or sub taxonomy slug inside this template file**, and also **how to know the current page is main taxonomy page or sub taxonomy page**.
please explain if you know the answer.

I to create `taxonomy-category.php`, but that is not working

Why are `taxonomy-category.php` and `taxonomy-category-main1.php` not working?
After creating these pages and view products by category it's display Nothing Found.

Comment: Your custom taxonomy **cannot** be called `category`. This name is already used by the build in taxonomy `category`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use category slug as its the default slug for WordPress category. Try register your taxonomy with some other taxonomy name like product-category and use taxonomy-product-category.php file to render individual taxonomy category layout(main1, main2 etc.)

[Function Reference/register taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy).